# Convert RAR to 7zip

Tags: windows, compression, 7-zip, rar

To convert a RAR to 7zip archive the typical approach is to unpack the RAR archive and the repackage as 7zip.

Without unpacking and repacking is there a way to convert a RAR archive to 7zip format?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  You cannot convert one compressed archive format to another without uncompressing.  This is because different compression programs use different algorithms (like different languages) and store the compressed data differently.  There is no way to get the data from a compressed file without decompressing it.

Here is an analogy: Say I have a book in English and took out all the vowels in the text, thereby compressing the data.  I ask you to convert this "compressed" book to Spanish, but also compress the Spanish by removing the vowels.  You cannot do it without putting the vowels back in (uncompressing) the English text to understand and read it, so that you can then convert it to Spanish.  *Then* you could remove the vowels from the Spanish text to compress it.